# Maven 3 install:install-file not working

Tags: maven

I want to install a jar file to the local repository using **maven 3.0.4**.

I used:

```
./mvn install:install-file -Dfile=~/Downloads/daozero-0.5.jar -DgroupId=daozero-DartifactId=daozero -Dversion=0.5 -Dpackaging=jar
```

It reported successful.

But in my project, there's still an error with daozero dependency.

I checked the file location `/Users/someuser/.m2/repository/daozero/daozero/0.5/` and found that there was no file: `daozero-0.5.jar`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>daozero</groupId>
    <artifactId>daozero</artifactId>
    <version>0.5</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Can anyone help me to understand what's going on?  It worked before in **maven 2.x**.

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar issue where the files were not being copied from a relative path.

Try using the fully qualified path of the jar file instead of ~.

eg:

```
./mvn install:install-file -Dfile=/home/user1942964/Downloads/daozero-0.5.jar -DgroupId=daozero -DartifactId=daozero -Dversion=0.5 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. I was banging my head on this for 1/4 hour. I love how it says success even if the file is not there.

Comment: Newer versions warn about the problem and do not report success. Force with 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5:install-file'.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old problem, just sharing my experience for other people,

I had the same issues, then I realized that I put a wrong name to the jar I am referring to.

Maven didn't complain and finished with success message, but didn't copy the jar :)

Regards
Lyju

Comment: This would really be better as a comment, although I realize you do not have the rep to comment as of yet.

Comment: @Lyju : I really appreciate your answer. This saved my time.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is the issue, but you forgot a space between one of your commandline parameters:

```
./mvn install:install-file -Dfile=~/Downloads/daozero-0.5.jar -DgroupId=daozero -DartifactId=daozero -Dversion=0.5 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution: You just have to surround the properties with quotes or double quotes like this :

```
./mvn install:install-file -Dfile="~/Downloads/daozero-0.5.jar" -DgroupId="daozero" -DartifactId="daozero" -Dversion="0.5" -Dpackaging="jar"  -DgeneratePom="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

I locally installed a jar using mvn install:install-file but Netbeans wouldn't let me add the jar as a dependency. Turns out the problem was with Netbeans.

I went to Services -> Maven Repositories -> local (right click) then did "Update Index". Then I went back to my project -> add dependency and was able to see it.

After doing "update index" don't bother looking at the tree, the new jar may not show in "Services". Just go back to the project and try to add it. Good luck!